# Usb Tethering not working in deepin os

Tags: linux, debian, usb, tethering

I have a Obi worldphone sf1 running on android 5.0.2 and laptop running on deepin 15.3.

When i connect my phone with the laptop via usb and start usb tethering, it says the device is removed, and it is unable to connect to the rndis device.

Following is the dmesg after turning on the usb tethering in phone

```
USB disconnect, device number 24
[ 1936.924410] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci-pci
[ 1937.017301] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=9024
[ 1937.017310] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1937.017314] usb 1-1.1: Product: Android
[ 1937.017318] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
[ 1937.017321] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 1937.020531] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device, 02:02:45:46:4f:48
[ 1937.580982] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device
```

Following is the dmesg after turning off the usb tethering:

```
USB disconnect, device number 25
[ 2031.379185] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[ 2031.473045] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f006
[ 2031.473054] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2031.473058] usb 1-1.1: Product: Android
[ 2031.473062] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
[ 2031.473065] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 2031.479114] hid-generic 0003:05C6:F006.000A: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Android Android] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
```

I have tried usb tethering my phone on different os, it works.

I have tried different phones for usb tethering on my laptop, it works.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong. I'm new to this all asking question on the internet thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the RNDIS interface is *unregistered immediately*:

`[ 1937.020531] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device, 02:02:45:46:4f:48
[ 1937.580982] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0 usb0:` **unregister** `'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device`

after turning of the usb functionality is a HID device (Human Interface Device) what is unusual (normal is USB storage) but this has no effect on the tethering (RNDIS host)

The problem is that the RNDIS interface of the phone is *unregistered* immediately after registration for unknown reasons.
Maybe this is a driver issue or a firmware issue. Check `lsmod` to see which driver modules are loaded. See also this https://superuser.com/questions/909237/get-usb-tethering-from-android-device-to-work-on-debian-8

Comment: Yeah, I think there's some problem with the os. Drivers are fine (usbnet, rndis) or at least it shows on lsmod | grep usbnet

Comment: the driver is *rndis_host* in the dmesg output and the interface usb0 is established for a short time. The question is why *usb0* is killed and why *rndis_host* is unregistered automatically. There are multiple versions of the *rndis_host* driver and maybe the firmware of the phone is not compatible with this driver version. Another possibility is that this is a security feature but this would be strange.

Comment: maybe you can try sniffing the USB traffic with wireshark https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

Comment: Yup, I have been trying figure out the same thing. And never tried Wireshark for USB sniffing, I thought it was only for internet sniffing.